# REST Client extension - API response as HTML

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wanted to use vs code's extension `REST client` for testing purposes. So I used a curl of an existing API running on my local machine. But instead of JSON, I got HTML as a response. The curl works as expected in the terminal but not with the extension.
The same Behaviour is with another extension named `Thunder Client`.

Postman is getting JSON responses for the same API I believe that issue lies within vs code itself, I just don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Sounds like the requests sent do not contain the correct `Accept` header. You have to talk to the extension developers or roll out your own extension. Has nothing to do with VSCode itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article:
`https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207835/is-it-ok-to-return-html-from-a-json-api`
If you have declared you only accept one format in the header then the service should only send back that format or throw an error. If you have not put an ACCEPT in the header, the the service may send back whatever.
Check what is in the ACCEPT header:

[image]

But also check how Thunder Client translates the call in powershell:
[image]

I see that in my call the response is translated to JSON. I would guess that most REST clients are assuming that users want to work in JSON. Maybe that's what your two REST clients are doing?

Comment: I don't know about the exact source of the problem. But after restarting my machine, it worked. There was not any ACCEPT header and it works.
But this information is something that might come in handy.